# Preserve Case in Route Parameters with LowercaseUrls enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` in my MVC 4 application which is working great. However, parameters will also get lowercased, so if I have a route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyController",
    url: "foo/{hash}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details" }
);
```

The link generated with

```
@Html.ActionLink("my link", "Details", new { hash=ViewBag.MyHash })
```

will have the `{hash}`-part of the URL lowercased as well, for example if `ViewBag.MyHash = "aX3F5U"` then the generated link will be `/foo/ax3f5u` instead of `/foo/aX3F5U`

Is there a way to force MVC to only lowercase the controller and action parts?

For older versions of MVC, the way to go seemed to be to implement a custom subclass of `Route`, however I don't know how/where to instantiate it, since the signature of the route constructors is quite different to `MapRoute` and I'm hoping there to be a simpler way.

Comment: Can you add an example of your routes that you wish to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution with a custom subclass of `Route` will be a good enough and simple, but at the same time a little bit ugly :)

You can add a `CustomRoute` at `RegisterRoute` method of `RouteConfig.cs`. Add the following code instead of `routes.MapRoute`

```
var route = new CustomRoute(new Route(
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new RouteValueDictionary() { 
    { "controller", "Home" }, 
    { "action", "Index" }, 
    { "id", UrlParameter.Optional }
  },
  routeHandler: new MvcRouteHandler()
));
routes.Add(route);
```

Implementaion of particular `CustomRoute` may look like this:

```
public class CustomRoute : RouteBase
{
  private readonly RouteBase route;

  public CustomRoute(RouteBase route)
  {
    this.route = route;
  }

  public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
  {
    values = new RouteValueDictionary(values.Select(v =>
    {
      return v.Key.Equals("action") || v.Key.Equals("controller")
        ? new KeyValuePair<String, Object>(v.Key, (v.Value as String).ToLower())
        : v;
    }).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value));

    return route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
  }

  public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    return route.GetRouteData(httpContext);
  }
}
```

However it's not an optimal implementation. A complete example could use a combination of extensions on `RouteCollection` and a custom `Route` child to keep it as close as possible to the original `routes.MapRoute(...)` syntax:

**LowercaseRoute Class:**

```
public class LowercaseRoute : Route
{
    public LowercaseRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, routeHandler) { }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        values = new RouteValueDictionary(values.Select(v =>
        {
            return v.Key.Equals("action") || v.Key.Equals("controller")
              ? new KeyValuePair<String, Object>(v.Key, (v.Value as String).ToLower())
              : v;
        }).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value));

        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

**RouteCollectionExtensions Class:**

```
public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
{
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url)
    {
        return MapLowercaseRoute(routes, name, url, null /* defaults */, (object)null /* constraints */);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
    {
        return MapLowercaseRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, (object)null /* constraints */);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
    {
        return MapLowercaseRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, constraints, null /* namespaces */);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string[] namespaces)
    {
        return MapLowercaseRoute(routes, name, url, null /* defaults */, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, string[] namespaces)
    {
        return MapLowercaseRoute(routes, name, url, defaults, null /* constraints */, namespaces);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings", MessageId = "2#", Justification = "This is not a regular URL as it may contain special routing characters.")]
    public static Route MapLowercaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
    {
        if (routes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
        }
        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }

        Route route = new LowercaseRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = CreateRouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            Constraints = CreateRouteValueDictionary(constraints),
            DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
        };

        if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
        {
            route.DataTokens["Namespaces"] = namespaces;
        }

        routes.Add(name, route);

        return route;
    }

    private static RouteValueDictionary CreateRouteValueDictionary(object values)
    {
        var dictionary = values as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (dictionary != null)
        {
            return new RouteValueDictionary(dictionary);
        }

        return new RouteValueDictionary(values);
    }
}
```

You can now use `MapLowercaseRoute` instead of `MapRoute`, so

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyController",
    url: "foo/{hash}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details" }
);
```

simply becomes

```
routes.MapLowercaseRoute(
    name: "MyController",
    url: "foo/{hash}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Details" }
);
```

exposing the desired behaviour.

Comment: is there s specific reason for using composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: I think in this particular case, no. But I believe that composition gives the higher flexibility, of course it's somewhat subjective :)

Comment: I extended your answer to include my solution, as suggested by [Jeff Atwood on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/best-way-to-award-credit-when-solution-is-based-on-another-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one simple way to do this,

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults): base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    { 
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (values["action"] != null)
            values["action"] = values["action"].ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
        if (values["controller"] != null)
            values["controller"] = values["controller"].ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}

routes.Add("Default",new MyRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = MyUrlParameter.Optional }));
```

See [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/12/19/solving-duplicate-content-issue-in-asp-net.aspx) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at private `RouteCollection.NormalizeVirtualPath` method you'll see that it simply uses `virtualPath.ToLowerInvariant()`. So there is no way to handle that. Even if you create your own route it will be lowercased.

But what you can do is to add hash after '#' sign i.e. `"foo/{action}/#{hash}"`. I haven't
 tried, but it should work. Just look at `NormalizeVirtualPath` implementation.

Comment: Does not work (generates a 404), where did you find the source code of `System.Web.Routing`?

Comment: I looked at it with Resharper. I'm not sure if I can paste it here. You can use dotPeek from JetBrains - it't free. Try also hash as query parameter, i.e. `foo/?myhash=aX3F5U`. I'm sure this will work.

Comment: And you may get 404 because you also should change your rout to understand new url pattern: `"foo/{action}"`

Answer (score -1):

It's simple as 1.2.3 ,

look at this example

```
   routes.MapRouteLowercase( // changed from routes.MapRoute
       "Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

It's simple to download and install it via Nuget, I use it.
***`PM> Install-Package LowercaseRoutesMVC`***

http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems to also just convert the path to lowercase...

Comment: Yeap just download the LowerCaseRoutesMvc and that's it.